# HTML5 Gallery remove download button and playbutton overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, gallery

I have a client using html5 gallery (https://html5box.com/html5gallery/install.php) for video gallery. I know how to remove the download button when it comes to regular html5 video using controlsList="nodownload" on video element and using css to create a play button overlay.How would i achive this when I use the html5 gallery

I tried a bunch of attributes listed in the how to link and non seems to be working, like 'data-showplaybutton' etc. this is my current code now.and what i see on the inspector

[image]

```
<script src="/html5gallery/html5gallery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
div.guide {margin:12px 24px;}
div.guide span {color:#ff0000; font:italic 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-
serif;}
div.guide p {color:#000000; font:14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
div.guide pre {color:#990000;}
div.guide p.title {color:#df501f; font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
</style>


 <div style="display:none; margin:0 auto;" class="html5gallery" data-
 width="600" data-height="340" data-skin="gallery" data-
 nativehtml5controls="true" data-onvideoend="onVideoEnd">
```

Answer (score 0):

I  removed the "data-nativehtml5controls="true" attribute from the native code. which removed the download button and added a play button overlay before video plays